# laravel and pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables
Game(id, name), GameCategory(game_id, category_id), Category(id, title).

Partial code of classes:

```
class Game extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
        protected $fillable = [
            'name', 
            'title' 
        ];
        public function categories()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('VanguardLTE\GameCategory', 'game_id');
        }
}

class Category extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
        protected $fillable = [
            'title' 
        ];
        public function games()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('VanguardLTE\GameCategory', 'category_id');
        }
}

class GameCategory extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
        protected $fillable = [
            'game_id', 
            'category_id'
        ];
        public function category()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('VanguardLTE\Category');
        }
        public function game()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('VanguardLTE\Game');
        }
}
```

I need to select category titles for selected $game

This code give me only category_id.

```
$g_categories = $game->categories->pluck('category_id')->toArray();
```

This code not working:

```
$g_categories = $game->categories->category->pluck('title')->toArray();
```

As You mentioned to do

```
            $g_categories  = $game->categories->pluck('category_id')->toArray();
            error_log('game_id'.$game->id.' category_ids:'.implode(",", $g_categories));

            $g_titles  = $game->categories->pluck('title')->toArray();
            error_log('game_id'.$game->id.' category_titles:'.implode(",", $g_titles));
```

This will result with log like this:

game_id1907 category_ids:39,48

game_id1907 category_titles:,

From database side we see that data(title) is filled:

```
select g.id, g.name, g.title, c.id, c.title 
from w_games g 
     join w_game_categories gc ON gc.game_id = g.id 
     join w_categories c ON c.id = gc.category_id 
where g.id = 1907;
```

| id | name | title | id | title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1907 | OceanRulerSW | Ocean Ruler | 39 | Skywind |
| 1907 | OceanRulerSW | Ocean Ruler | 48 | Fish |

Title in game is not necessary in this case but I added it here because have the same column name like title in categories.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing undefined relation .It should be

```
 $g_categories  = $game->categories->pluck('title')->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is incorrect and should be as follow:

```
 $g_categories = $game->categories()->pluck('title')->toArray();
```

you did not add parentheses for categories.

Comment: This give me only nulls. I added some info in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use laravel way:

```
public function categories()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('VanguardLTE\Category');
        }

public function games()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('VanguardLTE\Game');
    }
```

In this way you should name your table as

> category_game

and no need to define model for the intermediate table and you can simply access it through

```
$game->categories->pluck('title')->toArray();
```

in case you have any data in the pivot table just add ->withPivot('column_name') to your relationship

[Refer to Laravel documentation for details](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: I got working system and I cant change this relationship without rewriting much more code than I posted here. Maybe You can write simple query in eloquent to resolve this problem.

Comment: are you using w_ before your tables name in db, if yes try to add protected $table = 'table name as written in db'; in each model

Comment: I already added this protected $table = 'table_name_from_db'; This is working system with many functions in listed tables(>900 lines) but I think that is not necessary here to resolve My problem.

Comment: try to define all the foreign keys and local keys on all relations (not sure this will help), or you can try to use hasManyThrough relation